# Proving a projective quadric is nonsingular

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $\neq 2$. Let $C$ be an irreducible quadric curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$, i.e. $C = Z(F)$ where $F$ is an irreducible degree 2 form. I think we can see $F = x_0^2 + x_1^2 + x_2^2$ under a suitable change of coordinates.

I'm trying to show the induced rational morphism given by projection from a point, but first I'd like to see that $C$ is nonsingular, because I think I can get it from there. I'd like to try and use the Jacobian criterion, but the form we were given is in terms of affine varieties. I'm not sure I can directly see $C$ as an affine variety, so I need to show that in the process.

Comment: Can't you just look in each affine chart, i.e., set $x_i = 1$ for $i = 0,1,2$?

Comment: So, you're saying $C \cap D(x_0)$ is an affine variety, and so I can use the Jacobian criterion there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the Jacobian criterion directly for the homogenous polynomial and notice that the only point, where all partials vanish, is $(0,0,0)$, which is not a point of the quadric (it is not even a point of the projective space).

You can check Hartshorne, Exercise $I.5.8$ for details. A key ingredient is [Euler's Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html).